# enable or disable a button in javascript

Tags: css

I am trying to control the disable state of an input type button tag, via javascript.The browser I am using is Chrome. I have made a jsfiddle to simulate the problem, there is a toggle button that is supposed to toggle between the true and false state of disabled, and it is targeted specifically at the stop button. 
Here is the code:

```js
function toggleState() {
  if(document.getElementById("stopButton").disabled){
    document.getElementById("stopButton").disabled = "false";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("stopButton").disabled = "true";
  }
}
```

```css
/* code to reset the browser - compliments to meyerweb */
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 font-size: 5px;
 font: inherit;
 vertical-align: baseline;
}
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.WebRecallForm {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-left: 30%; 
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-family: Tahoma;
  color:grey;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 35px;
  background:#ECEEE9;
}
.NoteForm {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: Tahoma;
  color:grey;
  font-size: 12px;
  width: 100%;
  padding-right: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}
.WebRecallForm h1, .NoteForm h1{
 text-transform: uppercase;
 color:grey;
 font-weight:bold;
 font-size: 12px;
 padding:5px;
 text-align: center;
}
.WebRecallForm h2, .NoteForm h2 {
 text-transform: uppercase;
 padding:5px;
 color:#5e9dd1;
 font-weight:bold;
 font-size: 11px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 text-align: center;
}
.NoteForm h2 {
 text-align: left;
}
#horizonal-line
{
 width: 100%;
 margin-top: 15px;
 border-top: 1px solid grey;
 text-align: center;
}
.WebRecallForm ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
.WebRecallForm li { 
 padding: 5px;
 height:28px;
}
.WebRecallForm label {
 float: left;
}
.WebRecallForm li input, number {
 height: 21px;
 float: right;
 margin-right: 10px;
 padding-left: 5px;
 padding-right: 5px;
}
.WebRecallForm li input, number, select {
 height: 23px;
 border-radius: 3px;
 font-family: Tahoma;
    font-size: 11px;
}
.WebRecallForm input[type=number] {
 font-size: 11px;
}
.WebRecallForm input[type=password], input[type=text], input[type=select], input[type=number] {
    padding: 5px;
    width: 250px;
    margin-right: 10px;
 margin-left: 15px;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 
                0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(250, 250, 250, 0.5) ;
    font-family: Tahoma;
    font-size: 12px;
}
.WebRecallForm input[type=checkbox], .NoteForm input[type=checkbox], .NoteForm input[type=radio]  {
 height: 15px;
 width: 15px;
 border-radius: 3px;
 box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 
                0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(250, 250, 250, 0.5) ;
    font-family: Tahoma;
    font-size: 12px;
}
#period, #encoding, #nrchannels, #size, #periodRadius {
 width: 150px;
 float: right;
 margin-right: 10px;
}
.WebRecallForm input[type=password]:hover, input[type=number]:hover, input[type=text]:hover, select:hover, .NoteTextArea textarea:hover   {
    border: 1px solid #639FD2;
}
.errormsg {
 color: red;
 text-align: center;
}

.wr_button {
text-align: center;
padding: 2px;
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr = '#a5c4db', endColorstr = '#5e9dd1');
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr = '#a5c4db', endColorstr = '#5e9dd1')";
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #a5c4db, #5e9dd1);
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, center top, center bottom, from(#a5c4db), to(#5e9dd1));
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #a5c4db, #5e9dd1);
background-image: linear-gradient(top, #a5c4db, #5e9dd1);
background-clip: padding-box;
/*Use "background-clip: padding-box" when using rounded corners to avoid the gradient bleeding through the corners*/
/*--IE9 WILL PLACE THE FILTER ON TOP OF THE ROUNDED CORNERS--*/
opacity: 0.86;
-ms-filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity = 86);
/*-ms-filter must come before filter*/
 border-radius: 3px;
 color:white;
 border:1px solid white;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 margin-left: 15px;
}
.WebRecallForm input[type=submit]:hover, input[type=button]:hover, .NoteForm input[type=submit]:hover {
 border: 1px solid #639FD2;
 /*reverse the gradient colours*/
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr = '#a5c4db', endColorstr = '#5e9dd1');
 -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr = '#a5c4db', endColorstr = '#5e9dd1')";
 background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #5e9dd1, #a5c4db);
 background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, center top, center bottom, from(#5e9dd1), to(#a5c4db));
 background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #5e9dd1, #a5c4db);
 background-image: linear-gradient(top, #5e9dd1, #a5c4db);
}
.WebRecallTable {
 border-radius: 5px;
 border-spacing: 10px;
 background:#ECEEE9;     
 font-family: Tahoma;
 font-size: 12px;
 font-color: grey;
 padding: 10px;
}
.WebRecallTable td {
 padding-left: 10px;
 padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.WebRecallTable th{
 font-weight: bold;
 padding: 10px;
}
.WebRecallForm input[type=checkbox], input[type=radio], .NoteForm input[type=checkbox], .NoteForm input[type=radio] {
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 1px;
}
.WebRecallForm input[type=radio] {
    bottom: 2px;
}
.WebRecallForm input[type=checkbox]:hover , .NoteForm input[type=checkbox]:hover, .NoteForm input[type=radio]:hover{
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px 1px #639FD2;
}
.ModalWindow {
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 z-index: 99999;
 opacity:0;
 -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
 -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
 transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
 pointer-events: none;
}
.ModalWindow:target {
 opacity:1;
 pointer-events: auto;
}
.ModalWindow > div {
 width: 50%;
 position: relative;
 margin: 10% auto;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 background:#ECEEE9;
 text-align: center;
}
.ModalWindow .modalHeader  {    padding: 5px 20px 0px 20px; }
.ModalWindow .modalContent {    padding: 0px 20px 5px 20px; }
.ModalWindow .modalFooter  {    padding: 8px 20px 8px 20px; }
.modalFooter {
 background: #F1F1F1;
 border-top: 1px solid #999;
 -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 13px 12px -14px #888;
 -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 13px 12px -14px #888;
 box-shadow: inset 0px 13px 12px -14px #888;
    }
.modalFooter p {
 color:#D4482D;
 text-align:right;
 margin:0;
 padding: 5px;
}
.ok, .close, .cancel {
 background: #606061;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 line-height: 25px;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-weight: bold;
 -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
 -moz-border-radius: 2px;
 border-radius: 2px;
 -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
}
.close {
 position: absolute;
 right: 5px;
 top: 5px;
 width: 22px;
 height: 22px;
 font-size: 10px;
}
.ok, .cancel {
 width:80px;
 float:right;
 margin-left:20px;
}
.ok:hover { background: #189CDA; }
.close:hover, .cancel:hover { background: #D4482D; }
.clear { float:none; clear: both; }

.NoteForm {
  background-color:#ECEEE9;
  font-family: Tahoma;
  color:grey;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.NoteForm ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
.NoteOptions {
  display: inline;
  width: 10%;
  border: grey;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
.NoteTextArea {
  float: right;
  display: block;
  width: 89%;
}
.NoteTextArea textarea
{
  height: 120px;
  width: 100%;
}
.NoteButton
{
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-left: 11%;
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
 padding: 2px;
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr = '#a5c4db', endColorstr = '#5e9dd1');
 -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr = '#a5c4db', endColorstr = '#5e9dd1')";
 background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #a5c4db, #5e9dd1);
 background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, center top, center bottom, from(#a5c4db), to(#5e9dd1));
 background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #a5c4db, #5e9dd1);
 background-image: linear-gradient(top, #a5c4db, #5e9dd1);
 background-clip: padding-box;
 /*Use "background-clip: padding-box" when using rounded corners to avoid the gradient bleeding through the corners*/
 /*--IE9 WILL PLACE THE FILTER ON TOP OF THE ROUNDED CORNERS--*/
 opacity: 0.86;
 -ms-filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity = 86);
 /*-ms-filter must come before filter*/
  border-radius: 3px;
  color:white;
  border:1px solid white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#stopButton:disabled {
 background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #AAABAD, #1A2025);
}
```

```html
<form name="ExportToExcel" id="ExportToExcel" class="WebRecallForm" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="userGUID" value="${webrecallSession.userGUID}"/>
  <h1>Export to excel</h1>
  <ul>
   <li>Rows processed:<input type="text" id="count"/></li>
   <li>
    <input class="wr_button" id="stopButton" name="stopButton" onclick="stopTask()" type="button" value="stop" />
    <input class="wr_button"  id="downloadButton" name="downloadButton" onclick="showBusy(); document.location='/webrecall/excel?taskID=${taskID}'" type="button"  disabled value="Download" />
     
    <input class="wr_button" id="backButton" name="backButton" onclick="history.back(-1)" type="button" value="Back" />
   </li>
      <input name="toggleButton" type="button" onclick="toggleState()" value="Click me to toggle"/>
  </ul>
 </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting the value of disabled to the STRING "true" or "false". If you change it to the Boolean - just true or false - that should work

```
function toggleState() {
  if(document.getElementById("stopButton").disabled){
    document.getElementById("stopButton").disabled = false;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("stopButton").disabled = true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For better browser compatibility, set the value to "disabled" e.g.

```
<input type="button" disabled="disabled" />
```